# MS access cannot link mysql tables with compound or composite keys

Tags: mysql, ms-access, composite-primary-key, linked-tables

Scenario:
A MYSQL database contains a table with a composite primary key (the primary key comprises 2 columns like so:

CREATE TABLE `stations` (
`Station` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`Date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Station`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.

On a windows computer a "user dsn" to the MYSQL database is established via the ODBC Administrator. The driver is the MYSQL ODBC connector.

In MS ACCESS (2016) the table "stations" is linked using the "user dsn" for the MYSQL database.

In MS Access, the database connection works fine. The table is linked and appears in the access database. In the design view the database fields are all correctly displayed, and the two columns "station and data" are correctly marked as primary key. However, as soon as I open the table I get the error ODBC--call failed. And all the database fields contain "#Name?".

If I "import" the table instead of link it, all data correctly downloads and can be viewed and worked on in MSAccess.
If I remove the primary keys from the table in the MYSQL database, then the very same linked table correctly connects and contains all data.

Why is MS Access apparently uncapable of linking in MYSQL tables with compound/composite primary keys? Is there a solution or workaround?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I cannot reproduce. After performing (create table in MySQL, structure fixed, create linked table in MS Access using "x64 MySQL 8.0 ODBC Unicode" connector) both table constructor and table data are correctly accessible, data inserted/updated correctly.

Comment: It could definitely be an issue with the version of the ODBC connector. Then, I do question the interest of maintaining/managing composite keys, specially when these are non surrogate keys ...

Comment: `#Name?` in a linked ODBC table is rather caused by incompatible data types than composite keys IMO. Do you really use just `CHAR` ?

Comment: Akina: Does your table in the mysql database contain a composite primary key?

Comment: Philippe Grondier: I use: mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.23 and MS Access 2016

Comment: @ Andre: You are right, I do not use CHAR but varchar(8). The correct statement is: CREATE TABLE `stations` (
  `Station` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`Station`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.  The data types appear to be compatible, because when I just download/import the table into MS Access through the connector all data appears correct in MS Access, and if I remove the primary key it also works well.